# Config file issue / civicrm 4.6.8 / could not load the settings file

Tags: civimail, configuration

when I try to add external links in mailouts i get the following link:
https://MYDOMAIN.COM/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=300&qid=8370

when I click on it, there is an error:
Could not load the settings file at: /usr/share/drupal7/modules/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php

Civicrm is part of Drupal 7 in my installation. my php version is PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u1 (cli) (built: Sep 10 2015 08:34:47) 
the install runs on debian wheezy

please help..

edit: the problem seems to be in this function: function civicrm_conf_init() {

in the civicrm.config.php which is located here:
/usr/share/drupal7/modules/civicrm/civicrm.config.php

Comment: at a guess you have either a setting wrong in your civicrm.setttings.php or worse. your civicrm.settings.php file would usually be at sites/default/ - not somewhere within the civicrm directory

Comment: it is currently in sites/default/

Comment: I am guessing the setting in civicrm.config.php is a problem, because when I output the  $confdir variable, it doesnt make sense...

Comment: it outputs:" /usr/share/drupal7/modules/civicrm/../../ " as the confdir, which cant be right

Comment: when i directly set the $confdir in civicrm.config.php to "$confdir='/var/www/drup/sites';", then it works

Comment: i would avoid making changes before you are sure the basic set up is correct as per the documentation - though it sounds like you are familiar enough you may also find you are making further problems down the track. sorry i can't offer much more advice other than as a caution

Comment: would it be advisible to update the civicrm.settings.php file from the latest civicrm version? would that help? I think I am using a settings file from a much earlier version, when I compare it to the one that is shipped as an example with the 4.6.8  version..

Comment: Dan E - maybe check to be sure that you don't have a copy of civicrm.settings.php inside yr civicrm as well as at drupal7/sites/default/?  In yoursite/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php file how is CIVICRM_UF defined, as 'Drupal' or ?

Comment: hi! I have two settings files for two sites:
/etc/drupal/7/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php
/etc/drupal/7/sites/ANOTHERDOMAIN/civicrm.settings.php
the setting is: define( 'CIVICRM_UF'               , 'Drupal'        );

Answer (score 1):

I think CiviCRM expects to find the CiviCRM module in /sites/all/modules/civicrm, as per: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7

This affects the loading of the settings file, which is expected to be in a directory relative to this. We encounter the same issue and have a patch for it which we will submit back once it is a more generic fix.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems to be a solution to your specific problem but somewhat related and may help others.

The link `.../modules/civicrm/../..//default/civicrm.settings.php` is the default link when civicrm doesn't find civicrm.settings.php in another place.

In Drupal 7, if you have a site with multiple domains (e.g. example.com, subdomain.example.com), CiviCRM will only be able to find the proper civicrm.settings.php if you navigate using the main domain.

I have provided a patch so that civicrm can use the sites/sites.php to load aliases. This way, it's possible to have multiple domain in the same site and civicrm will not try to find the civicrm.settings.php in sites/default (which is not used in our case).

cf. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17521

Comment: I am still having the same issue after applying the fix